# How to find the survival ratio in each gender in each PClass?

Tags: python, pandas

I was able to find ratio on the basis of pclass or sex but i am not able to find the ratio of survival of each gender in each Pclass

```
df1[['Sex', 'Survived']].groupby(['Sex'], as_index=False).mean().sort_values(by='Survived', ascending=False)

df1[['Pclass', 'Survived']].groupby(['Pclass'], as_index=False).mean().sort_values(by='Survived', ascending=False)
```

How to join the above two conditions?

Here is the dataset:
[image]

Comment: Please do not spam irrelevant tags, that's a pandas question. Also use proper code formatting - done it for you this time.

Comment: To see the exact counts try `df.groupby(['pclass', 'sex'])['survived'].value_counts().unstack()` and instead of `value_counts` use `mean` to find percent survived.

Comment: @ScottBoston thanx . did'nt know we can group by on the basis of multiple columns like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pandas pivot_table for this:

```py
df.pivot_table('Survived', index='Sex', columns='Pclass')
```

If you want to see the counts instead, you can use:

```py
df.pivot_table('Survived', index='Sex', columns='Pclass', aggfunc='count')
```